# unable to write to hdfs using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to write data to hdfs using pyspark as below:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("example-pyspark-read-and-write").getOrCreate()
data = [('First', 1), ('Second', 2), ('Third', 3), ('Fourth', 4), ('Fifth', 5)]
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data)

df.write.csv("hdfs://<hdfs_server>:9000/example.csv")
```

I get this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o445.csv.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From <hdfs_server> to <hdfs_server>:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

my hdfs runs on port 9000

```
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS
hdfs://localhost:9000
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Dumb question... `<hdfs_server>`  isn't actually in your code, right? And HDFS is actually running?

Comment: Also, by default Spark reads the HDFS site file, so you don't even need to put hdfs:// paths

Answer (score 1):

In `spark 2.2` You can do like below

```
data = [('First', 1), ('Second', 2), ('Third', 3), ('Fourth', 4), ('Fifth', 5)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df.write.csv("example.csv")
```

You don't need to specifically pass the `hdfs path`. All you need is to provide the location where you want to store the `CSV` in `HDFS`.

The above code will create a `example.csv` directory in HDFS and all the csv files will be under this directory.

Comment: thank you for the answer. As you can see, I am very new to this. One quick question. There is a tool dynatrace that collects data points per application, JVM, Server etc. I am thinking about streaming this data to hdfs for longer term and run spark jobs on this data per app. Any ideas, how I can organize files in hdfs app_code_jvm_cpu_date.csv so that I know which app, and jvm and data frame this data belong to? Any recommendations?

Comment: @user1471980 you could rename the `part-0000` file under `example.csv` directory to what you want if you know how your data frame has been created. For example if you streamed your data from `twitter` and created  data frame from the streamed data then you can rename the `part-0000` file to `twitter_stream_abc_def.csv`

Comment: @user1471980 for this you need `hdfs dfs -mv /path/to/example.csv/part-0000 /path/to/example.csv/twitter_stream_abc_def.csv

Comment: I am not following your answer.